# Print struct pointer using function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

The problem is that the program does not print any values when using the pointer, I searched a lot and there seems to be no solution. any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Brok{
    string name;
    int age;

    void pt(){
        cout << "Name : " << name << "\nAge : " << age;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Brok *a1;
    a1->name = "John Wick";
    a1->age = 46;
    a1->pt();

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
...Program finished with exit code 0
Press ENTER to exit console.
```

Comment: You have a pointer that points to... *somewhere*. But most definitely not to a valid object

Comment: Hint: pointers are variables that point to other variables. Which other variable does `a1` point to?

Comment: "any ideas?" is generally far too vague a question to have a _correct answer_.  That said, the comments above should be taken as a hint that you might not yet understand what a pointer is.

Comment: @DrewDormann  Actually I'm not good enough at C++ and that's the problem

Comment: @sorax that's not an uncommon feeling!  In the scope of this problem, think about 1) pointers _point to things_.  2)  Where does your pointer `a1` point?

Comment: @DrewDormann yeah, I had to look at what is the cause, not just look at what in front of me

Comment: @sorax if you have more C++ work, you will find it much easier if you [turn on compiler warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/7jE41GGza) or try to [run your programmer in a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems).  Either one would have told you the problem in this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *allocate* the object a1 is "pointing to", e.g. `Brok *a1 = new Brok();`.

EXAMPLE:

```
/*
 * SAMPLE OUTPUT:
 *   g++ -Wall -pedantic -o x1 x1.cpp
 *   ./x1
 *   Name : John Wick
 *   Age : 46
 */
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Brok{
    string name;
    int age;

    void pt(){
        cout << "Name : " << name << "\nAge : " << age;
    }
};


int main()
{
    Brok *a1 = new Brok();
    a1->name = "John Wick";
    a1->age = 46;
    a1->pt();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brok *a1 ?  Its not set to anything just declared .....

This is how you assign the address of another variable to a pointer:

```
pointer = &variable;
```